# In Active Admin Gem,how to modify the view of resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have implemented ActiveAdmin in my Rails project. I have a resource called "Customer". In the navigation bar, there is an option called "New Customer" to create a customer. How can I change the view of this new customer? When I click "New Customer" button, it has to accept email from me, and it should send an invitation to that email-id.

Comment: This can easily be achieved by creating an `after_save` callback that sends the user an email. If `Customer` is set up with Devise, you could use the [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is follow this

https://gist.github.com/mikeatlas/5628317

it has enough details to setup `devise_invitable` with `active_admin`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can do it by, integrating ActiveAdmin and DeviseInvitable Gems. The following link illustrates that.

Here's [a link](https://gist.github.com/mikeatlas/5628317)!, In which they have explained neatly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Customer model has a email field, then you can just allow only the email to be shown in the form, and override the 'create' method. Something like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.input :email

  f.actions
end

def create
  #send the email here 
end
```