# In ActiveAdmin Gem, how to add invitation count to Admin model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, devise-invitable

In my project I have implemented [activeadmin](/questions/tagged/activeadmin) [gem](/questions/tagged/gem), which is integrated with devise invitable. So in my application admin can invite a customer through an email. While inviting, i'm getting the following error:

```
*ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::CustomersController#send_invitation
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'invitations_count' in 'field list': UPDATE `admin_users` SET `invitations_count` = COALESCE(`invitations_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1*
```

Comment: Did you add the `invitations_count` field to your `admin_users` table?
after enabling `invitable`

Comment: add your method also...where u have written your code for invitation..

Comment: see the answer i posted on your 1st question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743644/in-active-admin-gem-how-to-modify-the-view-of-resource, see if that helps here.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has happened after updating the gem **devise_invitable** to version **1.3.3**

To fix it just create a migration

```
rails g migration AddInvitationsCountToAdminUsers invitations_count:integer
```

That should add invitations_count field to the table admin_users

For others who has got the same problem but in another table. Here is a migration for a general table **users**

```
rails g migration AddInvitationsCountToUsers invitations_count:integer
```

Such issue could be caught by rspec

```
it 'user can be invited with passing current_user' do
  current_user_attr = {email: 'user1@example.com', password: 'xxxxxx', password_confirmation: 'xxxxxx', ... add your fields }
  user_attr = {email: 'user2@example.com', password: 'xxxxxx', password_confirmation: 'xxxxxx', ... add your fields }
  current_user = User.create!(current_user_attr)
  user = User.create!(user_attr)
  user.invite!(current_user).class.should eq(Mail::Message)
end
```